# Web Site Administration Tool Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, membership

I need to use in my Website, the Web Site Administration Tool (membership) available on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I need it to set Users on my website.The page is localhost, but I don't know where it is. Where is it (directory)? how to post it on my website?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0(v=vs.100).aspx

"To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the **Website** menu, click **ASP.Net Configuration**."

You'll also need your database and membership providers set up. The documentation is a great resource.

---

EDIT:
Creating new users without using the WSAT

You can use the **CreateUserWizard** control to add accounts. You can add them yourself or allow your users to register themselves.

- Creating User Accounts with the Create User Wizard [Video]

  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/creating-user-accounts-with-the-create-user-wizard
- Customizing the Create User Wizard

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.ASPX

Hope this helps

---

Good luck :)

Comment: I know where i open it. I need to know where (directory) it is to put it in my website

Comment: You want your users to be able to access the WSAT through your web site? Can I ask why? Usually if you want users to be able to register for and manage accounts, you have to set up separate pages for them to do so.

Comment: All time I create a user, I need to click in Project > ASP.NET Configuration (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) and create a new User. I want to put this page (create a user) in my website

Comment: Wakarimashita. Unfortunately, it's impossible using the WSAT. But I'll update my answer with what you can do.